# Dynamic, per server, embeddable graphs with InfluxDB

Tags: graph, influxdb, grafana

I have many server that I want to monitor with sensu + InfluxDB. I already created checks and metric collection with Sensu into InfluxDB.

I installed Chronograf to make queries on the DB and it's working like a charm.

But...

For all my servers, I want to have the same graphs:

- CPU usage
- CPU load
- Memory
- Disks
- etc...

Even if recreating them is very straight forward, I wanted to do it automatically. I want for all my graphs, the ability to choose the server I want to watch. All my data in the database are like this:

```
server1.memory.total
server1.load_avg.five
server2.memory.total
server2.load_avg.five
[...]
```

The queries I use for example are like that:

```
SELECT "value" FROM "metrics".."server1.load_avg.five" WHERE time > now() - 1h
```

I just want to find the way to select the right server for the graph I want to see.

Can I do that with grafana or chronograf? Maybe I have to develop my own dashboard, what is the best way to begin this?

Answer (score 0):

Chronograf has an undocumented API that will allow for the functionality you're looking for, but it's still in it's early stages and hasn't been tested extensively.

At the moment they're minimally documented on our end. It may require a bit of toying with to figure out how they work. Here's the list of routes for the API

```
POST "/api/v0/servers"
GET "/api/v0/servers"
GET "/api/v0/servers/:id"
PUT "/api/v0/servers/:id"
DELETE "/api/v0/servers/:id"
GET "/api/v0/servers/:id/version"

GET "/api/v0/servers/:id/query"

POST "/api/v0/dashboards"
GET "/api/v0/dashboards"
GET "/api/v0/dashboards/:id"
GET "/api/v0/dashboards/:id/export"
PUT "/api/v0/dashboards/:id"
DELETE "/api/v0/dashboards/:id"
DELETE "/api/v0/dashboards/:id/visualizations/:vid/cell"
POST "/api/v0/dashboard_import"

POST "/api/v0/dashboards/:id/cells"
PUT "/api/v0/dashboards/:id/cells"

POST "/api/v0/visualizations"
GET "/api/v0/visualizations"
GET "/api/v0/visualizations/:id"
PUT "/api/v0/visualizations/:id"
DELETE "/api/v0/visualizations/:id"

POST "/api/v0/visualizations/:id/statements"
PUT "/api/v0/visualizations/:id/statements/:sid/text"
PUT "/api/v0/visualizations/:id/statements/:sid/config"
DELETE "/api/v0/visualizations/:id/statements/:sid"
```